# Is it possible to load different string(xml) values in Android

Tags: android

In my app i want to load different string values from xml.
Almost like the different language.
I have multiple clients accessing the same app but they want different labels and styles. 
(An example would be I have a to do list tab. Client A wants it called day to day task. Client B wants it called task. Client C wants activity list. All 3 clients have the same functionality but want different text
Preferably. I don't want to create a new app for each client it would be a nightmare to maintain etc and I also don't want to make an if statement every time i want a the labels text changed. Ideally what I want is single application that loads a different  strings  for each client.

Comment: You mean u want the apps string values load in different language ?

Answer (score 7):

You could create a different buildType and or productFlavor for each client. For each buildType/productFlavor you can define a separate sourceset. This means that each buildType/productFlavor can contain a different strings.xml. The keys for the strings have to be the same, but each client can have a different string file within its buildType/productFlavor.

More information about buildTypes/productFlavors:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

e.g. you define two flavors:

```
android {
...
defaultConfig { ... }
signingConfigs { ... }
buildTypes { ... }
productFlavors {
    clientA {
    }
    clientB {
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can create for each customer a sourceset in your project:

```
src/
 |-> main (contains the common code/strings)
 |-> clientA
 |        |-> res
 |            |-> values
 |                |-> strings.xml
 |-> clientB
          |-> res
              |-> values
                  |-> strings.xml
```

In each strings.xml you can add the strings for your customer. The defined strings will also be merged with the strings of the main sourceset.

> How do you tell your application what SRC to use. between
>   Main/clientA/clientB?

You can build select the builtType/productFlavor in Android Studio.

> To work on files from a particular flavor, click on Build Variants on
>   the left of the IDE window and select the flavor you want to modify in
>   the Build Variants panel, as shown in figure 2. Android Studio may
>   show errors in source files from flavors other than the one selected
>   in the Build Variants panel, but this does not affect the outcome of
>   the build.

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants

Comment: How do you tell your application what SRC to use.  between Main/clientA/clientB?

Comment: By switching the BuildVariant. http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without build flavors?