# Android buildTypes for Alpha/Beta/Production apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build-type

I want to release my apk on play store. Initially I will release it on alpha, then beta and if everything goes well I will release it on production. Can we define different api endpoint for each in buildType inside gradle. if yes then how? As I just want to change the end point of API I am calling throughout my application. Like if I release my apk on alpha the api that it points will be http://test.alpha.bla.bla

for beta: http://test.beta.bla.bla

for production: http://test.production.bla.bla.

so in this my all version of app (alpha/beta/production) will be having same version code without any need to upload new apk.

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html . I think it will help you for what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to load different string(xml) values in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939270/is-it-possible-to-load-different-stringxml-values-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you mean you want 3 different build targets (and thus 3 different uploads to google play):
 in your build.gradle you have the **android** part, in there you can define **productFlavors** like the following:

```
 productFlavors{
    alpha{
         buildConfigField  'string', 'server','http://test.alpha.bla.bla'

    }
 }
```

But you could also make enums and refere those (instead of the type "string" you would have to specifiy the full package name + enum type , and in the last part (the value), the full package name + enum )

you can then reference the server by using (in java)

```
BuildConfig.server; //this would be http://test.alpha.bla.bla
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in `strings.xml`.  Each build variant can have its own copy with a different value.