# How to upload 2 different flavor apps in 1 playstore project

Tags: android, android-productflavors

Following is my app package name

> com.test.myapp

and I have created 2 product flavors, 1 for development & 1 for production like following.

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationId = "com.test.myapp.dev"

    }

    production {
        applicationId = "com.test.myapp"
    }
}
```

It works fine, when i launch app from android studio, it also creates signed apk fine, but when i try to upload `development apk` on play store, it gives following error message.

> Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name
>   `com.test.myapp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically it is not possible, Google not allows this, you need to create 2 apps on Google play for this. But why you need flavor for development with different package name? does Google's Alpha testing not solve your problems?

**Edit:**

Based on comments the issue was how to load different `strings.xml` based on build config without creating new package name.

Solution:

```
flavorDimensions "dev"

productFlavors {
    dev {
        flavorDimensions "dev"
    }
    prod {
        flavorDimensions "dev"
    }
}
```

Create new `strings.xml` resource in `dev` source set

`\src\dev\res\values\strings.xml`

I have uploaded demo project:

https://github.com/pavelpoley/FlavorTest

More info you can find in docs:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourcesets

Comment: Thanks @Pavel, Currently i need to comment out DEV urls to create prod build, and same for dev build, i want to avoid changing URLs, and want to create different build variants for dev & prod, so i just select prod variant, and it creates production pointed build.

Comment: But you can create buildConfigField's url's inside flavors for dev/prod

Comment: I am not using Base URL structure, there are almost 30 URLs inside strings.xml file, i cannot define each url with `buildConfigField ` :(

Comment: And how you wanted to solve it with 2 packages? different `strings.xml` for each build?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/35939452/5827565

Comment: Yes, actually i want to avoid the approach to comment out Dev URLs to create prod build & prod URLs to create dev build. So i thought product flavor is a good idea, but i end up not uploading build on playstore.

Comment: Maybe I am miss the point, but you can use flavors without create new package name, without `applicationId`, and just maintain separate `strings.xml` for each flavor

Comment: Yes, that's what i want, can you refer some tutorial link, or add steps in the answer.

Comment: https://github.com/pavelpoley/FlavorTest run this project and check if it helps you, change build variants dev/prod

Comment: This project really helped me in solving the issue, i just added ` flavorDimensions "dev"` in product flavor, and its now creating different builds without changing applicationId. Thank you so much for helping me, please add this in your answer. I am accepting it.