# need to change values in strings.xml file according to environment

Tags: android, string.xml

I am developing an android app. I need to use two google console projects for my dev environment and production. But there's a strings.xml file and I can not change their strings according to the environment. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939270/is-it-possible-to-load-different-stringxml-values-in-android) help you?

Comment: yes. It is also correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking to change String values depending on debug or release apk. Then you should put values in Gradle (build.gradle Module) rather than in String.xml values like this.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            resValue("string", "id", "your production value here")
        }
        debug {
            resValue("string", "id", "your development value here")
        }
}
```

and you can get this value in code like this.

```
context.getString(R.string.id);
```

This will show after you rebuild the project after adding the values in Gradle as these are generated compileTime.

I hope this helps and please mind my English as it's not my native language.

Comment: hi.. Is there a way to do the same for google-service.json file?

Comment: Forthat purpose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors This should be able to help you.